# A bouncing ball is bouncing elastically then it is SHM or not?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, kinematics, harmonic-oscillator, oscillators

A ball is bouncing elastically after its collision from ground so can we call it SHM as it is oscillating and also it is periodic and it seems similar to other cases of SHM? If yes then where is it's mean position? But the thing is in SHM force always opposes direction of motion but here it is always in the same direction that is downward force(due to g). Also in SHM force is zero at the mean position but here force is never zero.
There can be some flaws in my understanding of SHM as I am new to this. But all the answers are welcome!!

Comment: Not all periodic motion is simple harmonic motion. Just like not every periodic function is a sine function.

Comment: What definition of SHM did you learn?

Answer (score 2):

No. Simple harmonic motion (SHM) produces a sinusoidal variation of velocity (or position or acceleration or ... ) with time. The motion of a bouncing ball has discontinuities in the velocity vs time when the ball strikes the ground.

The motion of the ball is periodic, but it is not **simple** harmonic motion.

Answer (score 1):

> A bouncing ball is bouncing elastically then it is SHM or not?

No. A ball bouncing elastically when dropped from a height $h$ at time $t=0$ performs motions according to the piece-wise function:
$$
x_1(t) = -\frac{1}{2}gt^2\;,
$$
when $0<t<T/2$, where $T=2\sqrt{2h/g}$. And
$$
x_2(t) = -\frac{1}{2}g(t-T/2)^2+\sqrt{2gh}(t-T/2)\;,
$$
when $T/2<t<T$.

And then the motion repeats.

---

You can also see this is not *simple harmonic* motion, since the force is not proportional to the displacement. Rather the force is *almost always* a constant $-g$, except for at the moment of impact $t=T/2$ when the force from the ground acts to flip the sign of the velocity when the ball hits the ground.

In equations:
$$
F = -g+2m\sqrt{2gh}\delta(t-T/2)\;,
$$
where the delta function causes the abrupt change in velocity at $T/2$

Comment: Thanks I got this